# Ant/Ubuntu/Eclipse JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables, java-home

I have a problem when trying to compile a project with ant, whose build file was generated through Eclipse. At work I am running Debian and everything works just fine, also in the server.

However at home I have Ubuntu and when I try to compile I get the following error.

> JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>
> It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

So I edited my bashrc with the following lines

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

I restart my bashrc and I test

> echo $JAVA_HOME
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

fine, then I try to compile again but the error persists.

> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>
> It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Any idea on how to solve this? Ideally since the project is running on multiple machines, any change should be local.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH to have your JDK Path before the existing ones.

Comment: Can you make sure, that there is a full jdk installed under /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ ?

Comment: I am also using Ubuntu and java 7. I downloaded and installed the jdk under /opt/jdk1.7.0_07. The end of my .bashrc looks like:

[...]
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_07
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH

Comment: Yes there is a a full version, it is weird. I do not get why it is still pointing to a different directory.

Comment: Strange effect. You can try and run the alternatives-selector and check which jdks are available: 'update-alternatives --config java'.

Comment: thanks a lot, I kind of fixed it already, with a windows approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure this will help anyone but this is what I did. After going nuts I removed all java versions I had (6 and 7) and ant and installed them again (ant, jav 6 and java 7). Now it works.